# Azure Data Factory: how to get new file location from @triggerBody().folderPath without container name?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

When creating storage event trigger, path to the file that triggered the event is found in `@triggerBody().folderPath`. However, the path also contains container name. I would like to set my dataflow input folder dynamically by using `@triggerBody().folderPath` in data flow wildcard paths option. This option has container name already set. How do I get the path to file *without* the container name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.Nagative to the Manage page and click the code button of your event trigger.

[image]

2.change the parameter code from

```
        "parameters": {
            "folderpath": "@triggerBody().folderPath"
        }
```

to

```
        "parameters": {
            "folderpath": "@substring(triggerBody().folderPath,add(indexof(triggerBody().folderPath,'/'),1),sub(length(triggerBody().folderPath),add(indexof(triggerBody().folderPath,'/'),1)))"
        }
```

Then you can just get the folder path in your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the `@triggerBody().folderPath` for a *source dataset*, you can simply omit the `File system` field for the `File path` option:

[image: Omit File system field]

If the `File system` field is omitted, it is automatically assumed to be the first component of the `Directory` field, which matches the output from `@triggerBody().folderPath`. Note that in my screenshot above, I have configured my trigger to set pipeline parameters from the trigger parameters, then I am referencing the pipeline parameters from my source dataset.

I'm still puzzling how I'm going to set the correct path for the sink dataset though, as I want to copy to a different blob storage file system. I think I'll still need to use the hack from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67295151/).

**EDIT**:

I found a more direct method to strip the first n directories from a path:

```js
@join(skip(split(@triggerBody().folderPath, '/'), 1), '/')
```

Explanation:

First we [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#split) the path on the `/` separator. Then we [skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#skip) the first item. Finally, we [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#join) it all back together with `/` as the join character.

Comment: where do you put that at-join? I tried in the trigger, now the trigger doesn't seem to fire, and unsure if it's eventgrid being strange, or something else. I tried using that in (either the source dataset properties or the pipeline parameters) and that didn't seem to work, either.

Comment: I had a look, but I can't find the pipeline where I used this.

Comment: Thanks for looking. It appears to be in the Trigger Run parameters, inside the trigger- but I cannot for the life of me get yours to work. The other one does, but I tried numerous times - that other is UGLY, but it works. Sigh.