# SSIS Flexible File Destination FolderPath contains backslash

Tags: ssis, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

We are trying to get an existing SSIS package to work with Azure Blob storage. The issue is the FolderPath that we dynamically generate.

Our folder path is defined in a variable something like this:

```
@[$Package::BlobFolder] + "CATEGORY/" + @[User::FileDate] + "/SUBCATEGORY"
```

and then the file we are trying to upload is a parquet file so in the Flexible File Destination Editor we have something like this:

Folder Path:  (which is generated from the variable)

```
ourfolderpath/category/08152023/subcategory
```

File Name:

```
ourfilename.parquet
```

However when it runs the system concatenates the two values like so:

```
ourfolderpath/category/08152023/subcategory\ourfilename.parquet
```

which of course doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Note, here are a list of things we've tried already that didn't work.

1. add a forward slash to the end of the FolderPath, result: it just does this /\
2. add a backslash to the end of the FolderPath (this errors out and can't be saved)
3. add two backslashes = \ (still blows up)
4. replace all forward slashes with backslashes = does not work.

---

Updates at 2:30pm PST:

First I'd like to point out that the variable expressions I've posted above are just examples what they are like.  The real ones are much more complex (for what reason I do not know)

Second, I would also like to point out, that this whole thing actually works in production.  What we are trying to do is set up a development version which was apparently never done.

Third, we suspect that perhaps the error we are seeing is wrong and not in any way affected by the backslash.  The theory is this:

A) Which slash is used for concatenation is determined by the environment detected at run time.  If it detects a connection to Azure Blob then it uses a forward slash, if not then it uses a backslash (because this is on a Windows server)

B) We suspect the system is failing to connect, therefore when the error gets written it is written with a backslash since no connection was ever made to Azure making it seem as though the backslash was the problem when in fact it's something else entirely.

That's about where we are with it right now.  No idea why the connection is failing (or if that is even the problem)

Comment: Unfortunately not that, I'll add some more detail to the post because we have learned a few things since then.

Comment: any further luck with this? We have the same problem. I'm wondering if it's something like the fix we need when doing ADF with Triggers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294521/azure-data-factory-how-to-get-new-file-location-from-triggerbody-folderpath/74738786)

Comment: I see my last comment was August 15th.  That's particularly important to me because I had a stroke the following day, To be honest, I don't recall what happened to this issue.  someone else must have resolved it i suspect.

Comment: Well. Wow. In that case, I’m just glad you’re still with us ! Thanks.